# How do I get SSMS intellisense to keep my temp tables when I change DBs?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, intellisense, ssms

When I select into a temp table, after changing databases intellisense no longer recognizes my temp table.

[image]

The interesting thing is if I create the table via a `create table` query the temp tables will follow me.

Am I doing something wrong to cause this to happen or is this a limitation of SQL Server Management Studio?

This happens with both Management Studio 2008 and 2012 and with SQL databases 2008, 2008 R2, and 2012.

---

Here is a easy to copy version of the source to test yourself, you must be connected to a sql server that supports intelisense (2008 and up)

```
use [master]
select * into #foo from sys.tables
create table #bar (baz int)

select name from #foo
select baz from #bar

use [tempdb]
select name from #foo
select baz from #bar
```

Comment: I don't think you're going to find a knob or switch for IntelliSense that allows you to say "don't be stupid."

Comment: I don't know if it will help but cntrl-shift-r will refresh intellisense.  It does take a minute or two to refresh though.

Comment: @KennethFisher No, it is not a refresh issue. I have refreshed it it tones of times (via keyboard and the dropdown menu), in fact I wrote #foo first in my example then wrote #bar afterward (and #bar is the only one that works). Try writing my example yourself.

Comment: @AaronBertrand I thought maybe it is a issue of me being stupid doing something the wrong way, that's why I asked.

Comment: No no, I meant IntelliSense is stupid. If it doesn't meet your needs, you might consider Red-Gate's SQL Prompt.

Comment: I'm guessing the difference has to do with SELECT INTO begin minimally logged (similar to TRUNCATE TABLE) where INSERT INTO is fully logged but have no hard evidence to back that up.

Comment: I created a ticket on [connect.microsoft.com](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/788513/server-management-studio-intellisense-does-not-remember-temp-tables) if this really is a bug.